# How to make httpd response 200 for options request?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, options

I want to make some configuration on my centos+apache,let httpd server send 200 response when client make a options request.

There is a very old post here(2011).

[Returning “200 OK” in Apache on HTTP OPTIONS requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests)

The configuration may not be fit for current's os and apache.

If the configuration is in good status,`curl -X OPTIONS -i http://remote_ip/remote.html` may get 200 return code.

Herre are my tries:

1.cat   .htaccess

```
AuthName "login"  
AuthType Basic  
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/passwd  
require user usernam
Options -Indexes
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

Reboot it with `systemctl restart httpd`.Error info for command :`curl -X OPTIONS -i http://remote_ip/remote.html`

```
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
```

Delet the above config in .htacccess.

2.cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With"
    RewriteEngine On                  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.html [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

Reboot it with `systemctl restart httpd`.Error info for command :`curl -X OPTIONS -i http://remote_ip/remote.html`

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sat, 08 Sep 2018 00:34:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="login"
Content-Length: 381
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Is your question about how to configure Apache, or is it about how to provide the credentials in the client (`curl`)?

Comment: To configure Apache ,then check it with curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is an issue with your `.htaccess` file:

- In lines 6-8; you require that the user is authenticated, but only if it's not an `OPTIONS` request. This is fine.
- In line 4 however, you require that the user is authenticated as user `usernam`, regardles of the request method (GET, POST, OPTIONS, etc...)

So if you remove line 4 or move it into the `LimitExcept` section your config should work.

For more information see the [mod_authz_core docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html)

---

Second, the error message for the first solution you posted ("The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration...") hints at an invalid `httpd.conf` file. There may be something else misconfigured. Check your configuration and the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/).

---

As a reference, the config files I used for testing can be found at: https://github.com/mhutter/stackexchange/tree/master/467654

Answer (score 0):

The error `401 Unauthorized` means that the HTTP server expects credentials, usually a user name and password. Accoring to the question, you removed the `.htacccess` file that requested authentication, so there must be still something in the active configuration that requests authentication.

To provide the credentials, with `curl` you can use the option `-u, --user <user:password>` (short or long form).

---

When you get an error `500`, there should be an entry in the Apache logs that explains what king of error occurred.

---

When something doesn't work, it is generally a good idea to reduce the configuration to the required minimum to find the problem. To do that, comment out lines you think don't cause the problem and try again. Either it starts working, then you know where to look at more closely, or you have a simplified config.

With your config, the header lines probably don't contribute to the problem, but I would first try to get it working without the redirect. When you have a working config, you can add lines until either it breaks again or you have the config you want.